# How can I pause the video to stop it from playing in the background?

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout, tabs, video-streaming

I have a Tab layout with five Tabs (five fragments). One of them is for playing a video. Everything works well. However when I slide to another fragment from the video's fragment, the video continues playing in the background. How can this be stopped.

This is the Tab layout

[image]

This is the code to start the video

```
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
    return view;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check is your fragment is visible or not

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser && getView()!=null);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
              //fragment visible play video
        }
        else {
            //fragment not visible pause video
        }
    }
```

Comment: Let me try this

Answer (score 0):

Do this in the video view fragment 
    `@Override 
      public void onPause() {
          videoView.stop()
          super.onPause()
      }`

Answer (score 0):

This method is called when the hidden state of a fragment is changed.

```
@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
    super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);

    if (hidden) {
        // videoView.stop();
    }else {
        // videoView.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser && getView() != null);
    if(videoview!=null) {
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            videoview.start();
        } else {
            videoview.pause();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You must check that your videoview is not null also.